# How can I run .msi installer with administrator rights?

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer

As in topic. I want to run .msi installer but I cannot install a program because it requires administrator rights. As for .exe files I know how to do that.

EDIT:
My problem is that I don't have 'Run as the administrator' when i righ-click, shift-click, control-click or anything. On .exe files I can see that option but not with .msi.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Edited my queston.

Comment: Duplicate Voting to close other post

Comment: I browsed the answers, and all seem to be more or less OK. However, the easiest way to install an MSI with admin rights in my view is to **launch the install of the MSI file from an elevated command prompt** (right click **cmd.exe** and select "run as administrator"). Install with a command line something like this: ``msiexec.exe /I "MyFile.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log"`` (update paths as appropriate).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See: [Special Installation Instructions for the ActiveGanttVBA & ActiveGanttCSA Gantt Scheduler Components](http://www.sourcecodestore.com/Article.aspx?ID=10)

> To circumvent this error, extract and double click on the:
>
> `Install_As_Administrator.reg`
>
> File that is included in the Install_As_Administrator.zip file
>   distribution that can be downloaded from the top link on this page.
>   This file will modify the Windows Registry to include the following
>   information:
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\runas]
> @="Install &As Administrator..."
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\runas\command]
> @="msiexec /i \"%1\""
> ```
>
> Once the Windows Registry has been modified using the Install_As_Administrator.Reg patch you can right click on any Windows Installer (*. msi) file and select the option Install As Administrator and the .msi file will run using elevated permissions (Administrator Permissions).

Comment: A very convenient solution. +1

Comment: What does the `&` in front of `As` do?

Comment: It makes the letter "A" a keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 5):

Hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking on the MSI and then running as a different user and putting in my credentials allowed me to run my MSI. I did this even though I was logged in with those credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to **hold shift** then **right click** on the msi (or application) to get the 'Run as Administrator' option.
As detailed here: http://mockbox.net/windows-7/235-windows-7-run-program-as-a-different-user.html

Comment: This worked for me when the accepted answer (modifying registry) did not work.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/158118-run-administrator-add-msi-file-context-menu.html) is a reg file that will add the "Run as Administrator" option to the right-click menu for .msi files.

- Save the .reg file to the desktop.
- Double click/tap on the downloaded .reg file to merge it.
- When prompted, click/tap on Run, Yes (UAC-Windows 7/8) or Continue (UAC-Vista), Yes, and OK to approve merging the .reg file.
- You can now delete the downloaded .reg file if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Right click, Run as. Administrator -Easy as pie. By right windows SHOULD recognise its an installer and kick up UAC tho

Comment: Does not work on .msi files! See @Ichibann solution

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution that worked for me was to start a CMD as administrator and call/execute the .msi from there, by simply changing to the right folder and typing the  "filename".msi.

I really like Ichibann's way for a more permanent solution.

Answer (score -1):

This worked here. YMMV.
Some versions of windows block executables including .msi files. Find that in file properties:
Right click, find and click Properties (at bottom on my computer). 
Click the General tab (that's presented first here)
At the bottom find Security:
There's a message, 
"This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer." 
There is a button "Unblock"
Click it and the installer will start and perform correctly.

You may have to wait for the UAC dialog. If you don't OK execution in the UAC dialog, the installer will fail.