# How can I run .msi installer with administrator rights?

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run .msi installer with administrator rights?](https://superuser.com/questions/285167/how-can-i-run-msi-installer-with-administrator-rights)

As in topic. I want to run .msi installer but I cannot install a program because it requires administrator rights. As for .exe files I know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt as adminstrator. Navigate to the file and do `msiexec file.msi`.

Isn't UAC wonderful.